# CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream returns 0x800A0062 for Visual Basic 6 classes

Tags: c++, com, vb6, atl

I have C++/ATL-based COM object with method that accepts interface to allow callbacks:

MIDL

```
[object, uuid(...), dual, nonextensible, oleautomation, pointer_default(unique)]
interface IAsyncEvents : IDispatch{
    [id(1)]
    HRESULT OnProgress([in]BSTR message);
};

[object, uuid(...), dual, nonextensible, pointer_default(unique)]
interface IAsyncWorker : IDispatch{
    HRESULT CallMe(BSTR message, IAsyncEvents* events);
};
```

COM Object implements IAsyncWorker interface. The only method "CallMe" expects that client should pass "events" interface to allow callbacks from worker thread. "CallMe" implementation looks like the following:

```
STDMETHOD(CallMe)(BSTR message, IAsyncEvents* events)
    {                       
        IStream *pStm = NULL;
        HRESULT hRes = CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(IID_IAsyncEvents, events, &pStm);
        if (hRes != S_OK)
        {
            ATL::CAtlString str;
            str.Format(_T("Failed CoMarshallInterThread... %i"), hRes);
            MessageBox(0, str, NULL, MB_TOPMOST);
            return E_FAIL;
        }

        m_hThread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkerFunc, (LPVOID)pStm, 0, &m_dwThreadId);
        return ::GetLastError();
    }
```

And I try to call "CallMe" from Visual Basic like that:

**MyCallBack Class**

```
Option Explicit
Implements AsyncDllLib.IAsyncEvents

Public Sub IAsyncEvents_OnProgress(ByVal message As String)
    MsgBox (message)
End Sub
```

**VB6 com-object call code**

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("C++ Com Object ProgID")

Dim callback As New MyCallbackClass

obj.CallMe "123", callback
```

Everything looks ok but suddenly MyCallback class instances fail to be marshalled into stream. Meanwhile I can use "events" interface pointer from C++ implementation from the same thread.

CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream fails with undocumented error: 0x800A0062

What I do wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google "vb6 runtime error 98".  The code is weird, you marshal the pointer and *then* start a thread?  Wrong way around.  Make sure the vb6 callback is always marshaled back to its own main thread, it doesn't support any kind of threading.

Comment: @Hans, I should marshal before thread is started, otherwise what shall I unmarshall in a thread? I guess it's ok as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh, right, in and not out.  I prefer IGlobalInterfaceTable.  Well, runtime error 98 is all you got.  No idea what "private object" might mean.

Comment: @Hans, I tried to use CComGITPtr approach but error is the same with exactly the same code when I call "Attach" method on CComGITPtr instance

Comment: That's not unexpected.  Well, if you can't get past this hump then just marshal the call yourself with a hidden window.

Comment: @Hans, I have to exit "CallMe" method as soon as possible, leaving worker thread with visual basic callback interface reference. Where shall I create hidden window? Please, explain a bit more

Answer (score 2):

You cannot marshal private classes, standard marshaling needs a typelib to transport arguments cross-thread.

You can implement `MyCallbackClass` as a public (multi-use or public-not-creatable) class on an ActiveX DLL project in VB6 for marshaling to work or better implement a callback-proxy in your ATL component.

Your `CallMe` will create the proxy on the calling thread passing original VB6 interface then marshal `IAsyncEvents` interface of proxy object to worker-thread.

Comment: thank you! When I put callback object (MyCallBackClass) to another project (ActiveX DLL) - things become OK. I remember  that ATL project was created with flag "Allow Merging Of Proxy/Stub Code". I don't know where to look proxy-stub code at the moment but it looks like there is no proxy-stub code in a project.